# ¿Cómo puedo adherir funciones que quiten acentos y caracteres especiales a mi programa?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Hola tengo que hacer un encriptador de texto que además de encriptar cumpla funciones como remover acentos y caracteres especiales y sólo permita el uso de letras minúsculas.
Lo del uso de sólo minúsculas apliqué un .toLowerCase(); ... pero no sé como adherir las funciones que hice sobre los acentos y caracteres especiales. Comparto el html y el código en Javascript:

```js
// 1er funcion para caracteres:
function removerCaracteresEspeciales(texto){
  if(texto.constructor != String){
    return null;
  }

  var patron = /[^\x20\x2D0-9A-Z\x5Fa-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF]/g;  
  var resultado = texto.replace(patron, '');
  


    return resultado;
}
// 2da funcion para acentos:
function removerAcentos(texto){

  var aMayus = texto.replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]/g,'A');
  var aMinus = texto.replace(/[àáâãäå]/g,'a');
  var eMayus = texto.replace(/[ÈÉÊË]/g,'E');
  var eMinus = texto.replace(/[èéêë]/g,'e');
  var iMayus = texto.replace(/[ÌÍÎÏ]/g,'I');
  var iMinus = texto.replace(/[ìíîï]/g,'i');
  var oMayus = texto.replace(/[ÒÓÔÕÖ]/g,'O');
  var oMinus = texto.replace(/[òóôõö]/g,'o');
  var uMayus = texto.replace(/[ÙÚÛÜ]/g,'U');
  var uMinus = texto.replace(/[ùúûü]/g,'u');
}

// Me gustaría que quede de una forma similar al que aplique en el uso de minúsculas:
function incio(){
    document.getElementById('mensaje').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
        this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    },true);

}
```

```html
<body>
 
     <div class='texto02'>
          <h3>Mensaje Cifrado:</h3>
          <p><textarea id='mensaje'></textarea></p>
     </div>
     <div class='texto02'>
          <h3>Mensaje Descifrado:</h3>
          <p><textarea id="mensaje2"></textarea></p>

     </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que intentas hacer lo puedes lograr utilizando la misma metodología que estabas siguiendo. Para `toLowerCase` lo que haces es:

```
this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
```

Pues para las otras funciones sería:

```
this.value = removerAcentos(this.value)
this.value = removerCaracteresEspeciales(this.value)
this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
```

Nota que el orden es importante. Eso sí, debes arreglar la lógica de tus funciones. No estás retornando nada en `removerAcentos`, es una función que actualmente no hace nada. Te recomiendo refactorizarla algo como:

```
function removerAcentos(texto) {
    return texto.replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]/g, 'A')
        .replace(/[àáâãäå]/g, 'a')
        .replace(/[ÈÉÊË]/g, 'E')
        .replace(/[èéêë]/g, 'e')
        .replace(/[ÌÍÎÏ]/g, 'I')
        .replace(/[ìíîï]/g, 'i')
        .replace(/[ÒÓÔÕÖ]/g, 'O')
        .replace(/[òóôõö]/g, 'o')
        .replace(/[ÙÚÛÜ]/g, 'U')
        .replace(/[ùúûü]/g, 'u');
}
```

Y la primera cómo:

```
function removerCaracteresEspeciales(texto) {
    if (typeof texto != "string") {
        return null;
    }

    var patron = /[^\x20\x2D0-9A-Z\x5Fa-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF]/g;
    return texto.replace(patron, '');
}
```

El programa quedaría:

```js
function removerCaracteresEspeciales(texto) {
    if (typeof texto != "string") {
        return null;
    }

    var patron = /[^\x20\x2D0-9A-Z\x5Fa-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF]/g;
    return texto.replace(patron, '');
}

function removerAcentos(texto) {
    return texto.replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]/g, 'A')
        .replace(/[àáâãäå]/g, 'a')
        .replace(/[ÈÉÊË]/g, 'E')
        .replace(/[èéêë]/g, 'e')
        .replace(/[ÌÍÎÏ]/g, 'I')
        .replace(/[ìíîï]/g, 'i')
        .replace(/[ÒÓÔÕÖ]/g, 'O')
        .replace(/[òóôõö]/g, 'o')
        .replace(/[ÙÚÛÜ]/g, 'U')
        .replace(/[ùúûü]/g, 'u');
}

function incio(){
    document.getElementById('mensaje').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
      this.value = removerAcentos(this.value)
      this.value = removerCaracteresEspeciales(this.value)
      this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    },true);

}

incio();
```

```html
<div class='texto02'>
      <h3>Mensaje Cifrado:</h3>
      <p><textarea id='mensaje'></textarea></p>
</div>
```

---

Como sugerencia, puedes reescribir la función remover acentos cómo:

```
function removerAcentos(texto) {
    return texto.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
}
```

Quedando tu código:

```js
var patron = /[^\x20\x2D0-9A-Z\x5Fa-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF]/g;

document.getElementById('mensaje').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    this.value = this.value.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    this.value = this.value.replace(patron, '');
},true);
```

```html
 <div class='texto02'>
      <h3>Mensaje Cifrado:</h3>
      <p><textarea id='mensaje'></textarea></p>
 </div>
```

Ten en cuenta que para solo usar letras de la `a` a la `z` usa el patrón `/[^a-z]/`. Como lo tienes aún se admiten espacios y símbolos cómo `-` y `_`.

Comment: Genial!. Había escuchado de .normalize pero no sabía como aplicarlo. El código me quedó mucho más resumido y legible y anda perfectamente. Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda!.